# Aerospike: How to perform IN query on secondary index

Tags: predicate, aerospike

How to perform (sql like) IN queries in aerospike on secondary index. Do we need an UDF for this?

Something like this: Select * from ns.set where si_bin in (1,2,3)

Is there anything available in java aerospike client?

PS: Dont want a range query or that sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use predicate filtering. https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html

Python client [documentation for predicate filtering](https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/predexp.html) has examples for using the `aerospike.predexp` helper.

The Java client has [examples for class `PredExp`](https://github.com/citrusleaf/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java) in the repo.